# Obscure DateTime Format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a document with dates of the form 2014-05-14T9:15:20.  Unfortunately, Excel does not recognize this DateTime format.  Is there a way to tell Excel to read this as a DateTime format without splitting up the date and time?  If it helps this format comes from an XML document.

Comment: You could either convert the data "in-place" with a **VBA** macro or use a formula in a helper cell.

Comment: The date format is really Year-Month(day?)-Year?

Comment: That looks like someone's import code needs tweaking ;)

Comment: @'Techie007 It's not, thanks for pointing out the typo, pretty important difference.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Is that the only way to deal with this type of data then?  It seems strange that XML date formats are not well supported.

Comment: @114  The problem is the **T** in the middle of the string.............see my *Post*

Comment: That's not really an obscure date/time format. It is [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) which has been around since 1988. See also *[Parsing an ISO8601 date/time (including TimeZone) in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4896116/477035)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With input in cell **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,1,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,9999))
```

If you format **B1** as "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

you should see:

[image]

**NOTE:**

The format with the **T** is only valid **after the fact.**

This is, once you have valid date/time in a cell, you can then apply a *CustomFormat* of:

*mm/dd/yyyy"T"hh:mm:ss*

Comment: Thanks Gary, I still find it confusing that this format isn't actually valid considering how often I see it show up in XML.

Comment: @114 .............see my **NOTE**

Answer (score 3):

You can use this formula to convert

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T"," ")+0`

`SUBSTITUTE` takes out the `"T"` and replaces with a space and then adding zero "co-erces" the resultant string to a date/time value that Excel will recognise

Then just format in the required format, e.g. `m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss`